# Why do I get parse input error in this Haskell code?

Tags: haskell

The input to the code is numbers written in words "one" "two" etc.
the output is the sum of a all numbers inputed when "sum" or "end" is entered. "end" also exits the program.

This is the code that I've written.

```
main = addfunc 0


addfunc :: Int -> IO ()
addfunc l = do
 {
  input <- getLine;
  let n = myStrToI input
  ; if n == -2 
    then do {
          putStrLn("The final sum is: " ++ show (l));
          return ();            
          }
    else if n == -1 
     then 
           putStrLn("The current sum is: " ++ show(l));
           addfunc l;     <--Error Here       
    else  addfunc (n+l)
 }

myStrToI :: [Char] -> Int
myStrToI l
  | l == "zero" = 0
  | l == "one" = 1
  | l == "two" = 2
  | l == "three" = 3
  | l == "four" = 4
  | l == "five" = 5
  | l == "six" = 6
  | l == "seven" = 7
  | l == "eight" = 8
  | l == "nine" = 9
  | l == "sum" = -1
  | l == "end" = -2
```

The error I get is

`"error: parse error on input 'addfunc'`

`17.    addfunc l;"`

I've tried changing the amount of spaces or  removing the ';' in the line above, but I still get an error at that place. Is this error because the indentation of if else blocks?
I'm beginner to Haskell and don't really understand where the error is.

Comment: You're missing a `do` keyword on line 15

Comment: Can you please get used to standard indented style without `{` `}` `;`? Yes, Haskell allows C-like syntax too, but it's not really supposed to be used in human-written code.

Comment: If you do want to use the `{ .. ; .. ; .. }`-style, you should really use a consistent indentation. The one above is completely misleading. Just because indentation does no longer matter to the compiler is not a good reason: in C,Java, etc. it does matter yet it is still a must-have for humans. Also note that `;` is a separator, not a terminator, hence there must be no `;` just before the `}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `{` `}` (which you probably shouldn't), then did disables *all* indentation sensitivity inside. So your code parses just the same as

```
addfunc :: Int -> IO ()
addfunc l = do
 {
  input <- getLine;
  let n = myStrToI input;
  if n == -2
  then do {putStrLn("The final sum is: " ++ show (l)); return ()}
  else if n == -1 
  then putStrLn("The current sum is: " ++ show(l));
  addfunc l
  else addfunc (n+l)
 }
```

So what does the compiler make of that? Well, let's also move the semicolons around a bit:

```
addfunc :: Int -> IO ()
addfunc l = do
 { input <- getLine
 ; let n = myStrToI input
 ; if n == -2
   then do {putStrLn("The final sum is: " ++ show (l)); return ()}
   else if n == -1 
   then putStrLn("The current sum is: " ++ show(l))
 ; addfunc l
   else addfunc (n+l)
 }
```

Whoops. The `if n == -1` is never finished, instead you skip to the next line in the outermost `do` block, and there's then a lone `else` there.

What you actually need is another `do` for that `if` branch. Preferrably use indentation without braces:

```
addfunc :: Int -> IO ()
addfunc l = do
  input <- getLine
  let n = myStrToI input
  if n == -2 
   then do
     putStrLn("The final sum is: " ++ show (l))
     return ()
   else if n == -1 
   then do
     putStrLn $ "The current sum is: " ++ show l
     addfunc l
   else
     addfunc (n+l)
```

Actually I'd prefer using a `case` construct instead of those `if`s:

```
  ...
  let n = myStrToI input
  case n of
   -2 -> do
     putStrLn("The final sum is: " ++ show (l))
     return ()
   -1 -> do
     putStrLn $ "The current sum is: " ++ show l
     addfunc l
   _ ->
     addfunc (n+l)
```

Comment: In the OP code there are a few additional errors. One is `do { putStrLn (...) ; return (); }` where 1) the last `;` should not be there, 2) the `return ()` does nothing anyway here (OK, not strictly a bug, but...). Also, another extra `;` after `addfunc l` which makes no sense.